# Get all columns data in 1 row in email on google script

Tags: google-apps-script

[image]

I have this google script code that sends out email based on a condition. The code takes the data from different columns and the output of the email is as shown below:

Existing code:

```
function sendEmails() 
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 1; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 6; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A1:P300
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 13);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var dayofemail = data[0][12];
  data.reduce((m, [qua_num,manufacturer,model,serial,descrip,,,,daysPastCal,emailAddress]) => {
  if (daysPastCal > -14) m.set(emailAddress, m.has(emailAddress) ? [...m.get(emailAddress), qua_num,manufacturer,model,serial,descrip] : [qua_num,manufacturer,model,serial,descrip]);
  return m;
}, new Map())
.forEach((qua_num, emailAddress) => {
  var message = qua_num.join('\n') + '\nThe above equipment are approaching due date or out of cal.\nPlease check with QA for replacement or sending the equipment out for re-calibration.';
var subject = 'AUTOMATED ALERT: CHECK EQUIPMENT CALIBRATION ';
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject + dayofemail, message);
});
}
```

OUTPUT

```
QUA-014
COHERENT
J-10GE-LE
0303C15R
SENSOR
QUA-029
FLUKE
115
248301132
DIGITAL MULTIMETER
The above equipment are approaching due date or out of cal.
Please check with QA for replacement or sending the equipment out for 
re-calibration
```

I want to see the email as this:

```
QUA-014  COHERENT  J-10GE-LE  0303C15R  SENSOR
QUA-029  FLUKE     115        248301132 DIGITAL MULTIMETER

The above equipment are approaching due date or out of cal.
Please check with QA for replacement or sending the equipment out for 
re-calibration
```

How do I achieve this in google scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good example of not exactly maintainable code... Well, I'd try to add two `\n` to this line:

```
if (daysPastCal > -14) m.set(emailAddress, m.has(emailAddress) ? 
[...m.get(emailAddress), qua_num,manufacturer,model,serial,descrip] : 
[qua_num,manufacturer,model,serial,descrip]);
```

This way:

```
if (daysPastCal > -14) m.set(emailAddress, m.has(emailAddress) ? 
[...m.get(emailAddress), qua_num,manufacturer,model,serial,descrip,'\n'] : 
[qua_num,manufacturer,model,serial,descrip,'\n']);
```

And change `\n` to `\t` here:

```
var message = qua_num.join('\n') + ...
```

This way:

```
var message = qua_num.join('\t') + ...
```

But I can't check it, since you didn't provide a reproducible code.

Comment: I am able to get the data in one row with the change from \n to \t, but the 2nd row is indented (tabbed) from the 1st row data.

Comment: Did you add `,'\n'` after `,descrip`?

Comment: Yes I have. I have added a picture of how the email looks at the very top of the main post.

Comment: try to change `qua_num.join('\t') +` to `qua_num.join('\t').replace(/\n\t/g, '\n') +`